# My app keeps crashing, Cursor is not initialized correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-recyclerview

My app runs well on 3 different emulators (api 16, 21, 24 and 25) but keep crashing when tested on a real device. I get these error messages. but since i'm new in android programming, i don't really understand what they means. Im using RecycleView. the last method called is onloadfinished method where the swapCursor method is called. Thanks for your help.

```
09-18 23:41:30.699 8324-8324/com.a2sigma.workermanager E/CursorWindow: 

Failed to read row 0, column 0 from a CursorWindow which has 0 rows, 45 columns.
09-18 23:41:30.706 8324-8324/com.a2sigma.workermanager D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
09-18 23:41:30.719 8324-8324/com.a2sigma.workermanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.a2sigma.workermanager, PID: 8324
                                                                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                             at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetLong(Native Method)
                                                                             at android.database.CursorWindow.getLong(CursorWindow.java:524)
                                                                             at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getLong(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:75)
                                                                             at android.database.CursorWrapper.getLong(CursorWrapper.java:127)
                                                                             at com.a2sigma.workermanager.CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.java:56)
                                                                             at com.a2sigma.workermanager.CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.java:16)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5640)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3354)
                                                                             at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3886)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1197)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:131)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1389)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:868)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
                                                                             at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
09-18 23:41:30.720 8324-8324/com.a2sigma.workermanager E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
                                                                             at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:910)
                                                                             at android.view.View.layout(View.java:18874)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5954)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2697)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2413)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1550)
                                                                             at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7190)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:959)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:734)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                             at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:945)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
```

My AdapterClass

```
package com.a2sigma.workermanager;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.WorkerViewHolder> {
private static final String TAG = "CursorRecyclerViewAdapt";

private Cursor mCursor;
private OnTaskClickListener mListener;

interface OnTaskClickListener {
    void onEditClick(Worker worker);
    void onDeleteClick(Worker worker);
    void onWorkerClick(Worker worker);
}

CursorRecyclerViewAdapter(Cursor cursor, OnTaskClickListener listener) {
    Log.d(TAG, "CursorRecyclerViewAdapter: Constructor called");
    mCursor = cursor;
    mListener = listener;
}

@Override
public WorkerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder: new view requested");
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.worker_list_items, parent,false);
    return new WorkerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(WorkerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: starts position " +position );

    if((mCursor == null)||(mCursor.getCount() == 0)){
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: providing instructions");
        holder.name.setText(R.string.instructions_heading);
        holder.noIndukKaryawan.setText(R.string.instructions);
        holder.editButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
            throw new IllegalStateException("Couldn't move cursor to position " +position);
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: Hallooooooooo");
        final Worker worker = new Worker(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns._ID)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.NAMA_KARYAWAN)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.JENIS_KELAMIN)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.TGL_LAHIR)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.TEMPAT_LAHIR)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.NKTP)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.NO_HP_1)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.NO_HP_2)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.NO_KK)),
                mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.IBU_KANDUNG)),
     mCursor.getBlob(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.FOTO)));



        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: worker id "+ worker.getId());
        holder.name.setText(worker.getmName());
        holder.noIndukKaryawan.setText("NIK: " + worker.getmNIK());
        holder.editButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//TODO add onClick listener
        holder.deleteButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //TODO add onClick Listener

        View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starts");
                switch (view.getId()){
                    case R.id.wli_edit:
                        if(mListener != null){
                            mListener.onEditClick(worker);
                        }

                        break;
                    case R.id.wli_delete:
                        if(mListener!=null){
                            mListener.onDeleteClick(worker);
                        }

                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.d(TAG, "onClick: found unexpected button id");
                }
            }
        };

        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItemCount: starts");
    if((mCursor == null) || (mCursor.getCount() == 0)){
        return 1; // fib, because we populate a single viewHolder with instructions
    }else {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }
}

/**
 * Swap in a new Cursor, returning the old Cursor.
 * The returned old Cursor is <em>not</em> closed.
 *
 * @param newCursor The new cursor to be used
 * @return Returns the previously set Cursor, or null if there wasn't one.
 * If the given new Cursor is the same instance as the previously set
 * Cursor, null is also returned.
 */
Cursor swapCursor(Cursor newCursor){
    Log.d(TAG, "swapCursor: Called");
    if(newCursor == mCursor){
        return null;
    }

    final Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    mCursor = newCursor;
    if(newCursor !=null){
        // notify the observers about the new cursor
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else {
        // notify the obeservers about the lack of a data set
        notifyItemRangeRemoved(0, getItemCount());
    }
    return oldCursor;
}

static class WorkerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private static final String TAG = "TaskViewHolder";

    TextView name = null;
    TextView noIndukKaryawan = null;
    ImageButton editButton = null;
    ImageButton deleteButton = null;


    public WorkerViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        Log.d(TAG, "TaskViewHolder: starts");

        this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wli_name);
        this.noIndukKaryawan = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.wli_nik);
        this.editButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wli_edit);
        this.deleteButton = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wli_delete);
    }
}
}
```

XML FILES 
1. Worker_list_items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wli_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/wli_edit"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Nama Karyawan" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/wli_nik"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/wli_edit"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/wli_name"
    tools:text="123.256.478" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/wli_delete"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/wli_edit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/edit_button"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/wli_delete"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/wli_delete"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the RycycleView XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/worker_list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: looks like this is not the entire stacktrace... can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: Do you have `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in your xml's `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @MosesAprico No, i dont, ive edited my question.

Comment: @10101010 actually thats all i have

Comment: Wow man it's 4am in the morning lol. Btw, have you try to debug using breakpoints? It usually shows the problem for weird things like this.

Comment: Ok so this is better, but definitely need to know more about the crash or error receiving. I think you are looking at the ripple effect error, can you change your dropdown to "ERROR" only and look for "blue words" in the debugger that are clickable. It should show you exactly which line is not happy and then we could figure out what is going on.

Comment: @10101010  You guys were right, I edited my question again. :) sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's typically an inflation error. You would need to compare the View IDs that you are attempting to populate, make sure they are not null and that you are setup with your Recycler View Holder Adapter properly.

Post your adapter, your xml for the row that you are filling, your viewholder pattern and your adapter setup and assignment and we can certainly get you squared away.

Just to update the answer your cursor should be populated properly before accessing it and you should ensure the content exists before accessing it.

EXAMPLE populating Cursor

```
    Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            cursor = queryBuilder.query(MySQLDBHelper.openDatabase(<YOUR CONTEXT>), projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return cursor;
```

Next when you decide to access values from the cursor you can do some safe checks instead of directly accessing them. It can get rather verbose so I would recommend making a method that creates your object from the cursor and then do all your null safe checks there.

Instead of:

```
mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.IBU_KANDUNG)));
```

Do something like:

```
int IBU_KANDUNG_INDEX = mCursor.getColumnIndex(WorkersContract.Columns.IBU_KANDUNG);
myObject.setString(mCursor.getString(IBU_KANDUNG_INDEX) == null ? "" : mCursor.getString(IBU_KANDUNG_INDEX));
```

This will ensure you are not setting null values into your object or trying to access -1 index of a cursor that is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your quick respond, Ive edited my question with xml and adapter class.

Comment: Sorry could have responded here, can you get a bit more on the error side for me. The inflator error basically failed to create your UI element, but there is an underlying reason. It could be that the swap cursor happens while it is drawing your first row or a million other reasons, but I'm sure there is a bit more info nested in those logs maybe we can find it :)

Comment: Ahh ok that helped. Perfect. So you have a valid cursor object, but it is empty. You are crashing because your cursor content was not properly populated from the DB. So wherever you are creating your Cursor from (which is usually in a contentProvider of some sort you are formatting something incorrectly or encountering an error in your SQL possibly. At any rate, your cursor does not have the DB content, so getString will crash your app on trying to populate UI elements.